# Fix table row height

Tags: html, html-table

I want to fix the height of the tr in which there is a photo in first column. How to fix the height of the row and photo will auto maintain in ratio to be smaller if photo has great height. How to do?

Comment: Post your code please.

Answer (score 1):

not exactly sure if I understand your question, but maybe this is your solution. These are the CSS definitions you'll need:

```css
td { height: 100px }
    
td img { height:100% }
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><img src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/da2/boys-playing-soccer-5-1310832.jpg" alt=""></td>
 <td>Text text text</td> 
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td ><img src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/148/music-maker-1388555.jpg" alt=""></td>
 <td>Text text text</td> 
 </tr>  
</table>
```

Be sure to put the CSS in the td, not the tr tag!